# Class for circles circumference thinks operation is a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, math

Simple program but I am getting the error saying:

"Circle::getCircumference: non standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member."

I want to also have a string pointer to set the name for each of the circles. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Circle
{
private:
double pi = 3.14;
double radius;

public:

void setRadius(double r)
{
    radius = r;
}

double getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}

double getArea()
{
    return pi* radius * radius;
}

double getCircumference()
{
    return 2 * pi * radius;
}
};

int main()
{
Circle circle1;
Circle circle2;
double circRad1;
double circRad2;

cout << "Enter the radius for cirle 1: ";
cin >> circRad1;

cout << "Enter the radius for cirle 2: ";
cin >> circRad2;

circle1.setRadius(circRad1);
circle2.setRadius(circRad2);

cout << "Circle 1 radius: " << circle1.getRadius() << "\n";
cout << "Circle 1 area: " << circle1.getArea() << "\n";
cout << "Circle 1 circumfrence: " << circle1.getCircumference << "\n";
cout << "\n";

cout << "Circle 2 radius: " << circle2.getRadius() << "\n";
cout << "Circle 2 area: " << circle2.getArea() << "\n";
cout << "Circle 2 circumfrence: " << circle2.getCircumference << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add parenthesis to `circle1.getCircumference`

Comment: Thanks! I miss small things like that :/. Still kinda new. Thanks!